# cobol application on W8

Tags: compatibility, cobol

I have an application written in Cobol that runs on PCs with XPSP3 32bit.
I changed my pc and now I have windows 8.1 64bit.
I tried to run the program on pc with W8, but does not work.
I also tried with "compatibilty troubleshooting" in the property, but it does not work.
Do you have suggestions?
tks a lot

Comment: Do you have the Cobol source code and compiler available?  If Windows 8 XP compatibility doesn't work, then you're out of options.

Comment: Hi, Gilbert. I do not have the source

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc
if I recover the source, which compiler should I use to be able to compile for W8.1 64-bit? tks..

Comment: Any COBOL compile which works on Windows 8. GnuCOBOL is open-source and very good. Good support. See here: https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/discussion/?source=navbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Try "run as administrator"
- Run Win XP in a virtual machine [How to](http://www.howtogeek.com/171395/how-to-get-windows-xp-mode-on-windows-8/)

Answer (score -1):

32bit compiled Cobol program won't run on windows 64bit.  you will need windows 8 32bit

Comment: No. You don't even know which compiler is being used in the question, and you assert that *all* compiled 32-bit COBOL programs will fail to run on 64-bit Windows [8]. If I can do that with one program, then your statement is not true. Your statement is not true, therefore misleads and is not much use to anyone.

Comment: @BillWoodger It would seem to me that when new users join the site, and you have contrary information--it paints a better first impression if you would say *"Actually...this is not the case, and depends on the compiler and its capabilities.  I've successfully built X program using Y compiler and it ran on 64-bit Windows 8.  See my answer: `[link]`."*

Comment: @HostileFork A better impression where? The user is suggesting that anyone with this problem just changes from Windows8 64-bit, to 32-bit. Because of the language of the *source code*. If you want to wrap that up more nicely than "No", you're welcome. It is a baseless assertion with no content or worth, already contradicted by the other answer and other comments.

Comment: @HostileFork appreciate your contribution on this one, rather than continuing here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289266/1927206